# Полнотекстовый поиск (облако или не облако)

Tags: mysql, файлы, azure, полнотекстовый-поиск, облако

Ситуация следующая: на сервере лежит более 4-х ТБ файлов. Нужно организовать полнотекстовый поиск по этим файлам. Например, я ввожу несколько предложений и хочу получить все файлы, которые содержат эти предложения. Как проще это организовать?

Поступило предложение залить эти файлы с сервера в облако, якобы они поддерживают такую функцию. В облаках не очень разбираюсь, потому вопрос: стоит ли такой способ затрат, или есть другие, более дешевые варианты?

Answer (score 0):

организация индексации в облаке конечно же проще, но явно выйдет дороже локального решения.
Если вас интересует только облако Azure - оно поддерживает индексацию файлов с использованием сервиса [Azure Search](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#indexing-documents-along-with-related-data) для файлов хранящихся в Azure blob storage.